# Why does using push_back on a vector declared with size result in a vector of zeros?

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures

I made a vector of constant size to store negative values, and then printing the values all I got was zeroes. I just want to know why it is not storing negative values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(5);
    v.push_back(-1);
    v.push_back(-2);
    v.push_back(-3);
    v.push_back(-4);
    v.push_back(-5);

    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
       std::cout << v[i] << " ";  // All I got was zeroes
}
```

Comment: That's a *pretty* good [mcve]. The next step would've been to test your assumptions, the most applicable of which is that `std::vector<int> v(5)` constructs an empty vector with a capacity of 5 elements. This is fairly easy to test by checking [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) or printing out the `.size()` of the vector (although the latter may involve an assumption about what "size" means, which you should also test).

Comment: IMO, the easiest way to debug this is to check the value of the last element, in this case it would be `v.back()`.

Comment: It tends to be a good idea to loop from `0` to `size()` (instead of a hard-coded value) if you want to loop over a container (or, better yet, use `for (int i: v)`) - this makes it easier to spot bugs like this one and makes it easier to increase the size of the container, if you want to do that one day.

Comment: if wanting to use a constant sized vector, look at std::array  instead

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That's because `push_back` puts *new* elements onto the end of the vector.

You can see the effect by running `i` to `9`: the negative numbers will occupy `v[5]` to `v[9]`.

Writing

```
std::vector<int> v{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5};
```

instead is a particularly elegant fix.

Comment: @SuhailAkhtar: Not a bad question at all: Java does it the other way round where the constructor argument sets the *capacity*.

Comment: i thought that size was fixed so it can not go beyond its size, it will have to put new elements in required capacity. I was wrong.

Comment: @SuhailAkhtar that restriction (maximum size fixed at runtime) is correct for [array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array)s. The increased flexibility of vectors, combined with their (typically) small runtime overhead makes them so popular compared to the "classic" array type.

Comment: You're an elegant fix.

Comment: @Bathsheba in c++ one would use an `std::array<int, 5>` for a fixed sized container of capacity 5

Answer (score 25):

The constructor that you invoke fills the first 5 elements with zeros, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (#3 in the list of overloads):

> Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T

(where the "default-inserted instance" of an `int` is 0). What you might have wanted is

```
std::vector<int> v;

v.reserve(5); /* Prevent unnecessary allocations as you know the desired size. */

v.push_back(-1);
/* ... */
```

An alternative using the original constructor call is

```
#include <numeric>

std::vector<int> v(5);

std::iota(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), -v.size());
```

though this does more work than necessary as every element is first default constructed and then assigned to a new value again.

Answer (score 12):

This is a case where the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY_principle) would help you understand your mistake.

> `vector<int> v(5);`
>
> ...
>
> `for(int i=0;i<5;i++)`

Here you are creating an array, for which you think you reserve space for 5 elements. Then you insert those 5 elements. After that you wanted to print contents of the whole array, but instead of just writing `v.size()`, you repeated the `5`, so that your code now reads like "Print first five elements of `v`", instead of "Print all elements of `v`".

If you instead wrote what you mean, you'd see that the array actually has 10 elements, not 5.

BTW, since C++11 you can loop over *all elements* in a more straightforward way:

```
for(int x : v)
```

or, if the elements were some more copy-expensive type, you could use references to the elements, even `auto`-type references:

```
for(auto& x : v)
```

This new `for`-loop syntax is called the [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 6):

You can consider the `vector` a flexible version of the primitive array in C/C++. When you initialize a `vector` with a size `n`, the constructed `vector` has size of `n` (or maybe larger in the memory, but you don't know since it's implicitly handled by compiler). Note that here `n` represents the number of entries, but not the actual memory usage (i.e. bytes). If you do not initialize it with a size parameter, the `vector` is empty with size 0, but in the memory it would have some implicit default memory size.

Let's say your current `vector` has size 5. And you want to `push_back()` in another element, then the `vector` internally will reallocate the entire array into a new memory location which could hold all its old entries plus the new one. So you don't need to reallocate the memory manually by yourself, like what you have to do in C.

Here, in your example, to fill in those 5 negative integers in your `vector`, there are a couple of ways.

1) You can initialize a `vector` without specifying the size. And then push in each element you want.

```
vector<int> v;
for (int i = -1; i >= -5; --i) {
    v.push_back(i);
}
```

2) You can initialize the `vector` in your way with that size parameter. And then assign them with new values.

```
vector<int> v(5);
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    v[i] = -i;
}
```

3) You can also initialize the `vector` with those entries when it is constructed.

```
    vector<int> v{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5};
or  vector<int> v = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5};
```

Comment: In C/C++?.. There's no `array` in C — only plain C-style arrays.

Comment: @Ruslan I mentioned **primitive** array

Comment: Then it shouldn't be in monospaced font, since it's not code in this case.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared the vector with

```
std::vector<int> v(5);
```

You made `v` store five 4-byte spaces in memory (assuming an int = 4 bytes on your system), and by default all of these 4-byte spaces store the bits representing 0's. Then, you pushed 5 more ints (-1, -2, -3, -4, -5) onto the end of the vector with:

```
v.push_back(-1);
v.push_back(-2);
v.push_back(-3);
v.push_back(-4);
v.push_back(-5);
```

At this point the vector has 10 elements, the first five being the unknown ints that happen to store 0's on the instance you ran the program. Since your for loop prints the first five elements in the vector, this is why it printed all 0's.

Comment: It's not pure chance. `std::vector`'s constructor used value-initializes the elements it stores. For built-in types, value-initialization is defined to be zeroing. And whether it's "4-byte" or not is irrelevant to the OP's problem, as is the bit representation of these values.

Comment: @Ruslan If bit representation is irrelevant then how does the computer store 0's?

Comment: Regardless of how it stores zeros, the outcome of the OP's code will be the same. Bits would come into play only if there were bitwise operations in the code, but there aren't any.

Comment: @Ruslan Am I wrong in asserting that the first five elements of the vector store bits representing 0's? Maybe that's not important to the OP's question, but I don't see how it's faulty of me to mention it.

Comment: That's not wrong if we assume the most common CPUs with two's complement negative numbers. But C++ also allows integers to be in the one's complement or sign-magnitude representation. The main wrong thing is that you say that the ints pushed are "unknown" and "happen" to store 0s, while they are actually very well known — and guaranteed to have zeros by definition of value-initialization and the prescribed behavior of the `std::vector` constructor used.

Answer (score 0):

When you declared this line `vector<int>v(5)` it created a vector of size 5 with default value of all elements 0, at this stage your vector looks like this -
`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`

Now when you called `v.push_back(-1)` what it did is it pushed -1 to the back of vector increasing its size, now your vector looks like this -
`{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}`

After every push back is performed your final vector will be - `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5}`

The size of your vector is now increased to 10 from 5 and when you looped from index 0 to 4 it only printed 0. I hope I explained it well and fix for this is already provided in previous answers.