# std::vector has lower performance when size is set?

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Today I wanted to check performance of three different methods of iterating over `std::vector` in C++. The results aren't really that surprising, but something else caught my attention. I noticed, that if I create a `vector` and predefine its size in the constructor, some things are nearly two times slower. Please take a look at the results:

```
default constructor...
pushing data...
elapsed: 3.85164s
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) (*vec)[i]++; - 0.127319s
for ( int i = 0; i < vec->size( ); i++ ) (*vec)[i]++; - 0.128894s
for ( int &n : *vec ) n++; - 0.127325s

vector(N) constructor...
vec.size() is now 500000000
pushing data...
elapsed: 3.93543s
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) (*vec)[i]++; - 0.126036s
for ( int i = 0; i < vec->size( ); i++ ) (*vec)[i]++; - 0.252865s
for ( int &n : *vec ) n++; - 0.254146s
```

`N` is constant and equals 500000000. The vector contains only `int`s of random values (`rand()`). Each of the loops increments all vector elements. I'm measuring the time with `gettimeofday()` POSIX call.

This is the full source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/time.h>

const int N = 500000000;

//For time measurements
static struct timeval t0, t1, tdiff;
static inline void measure_begin( )
{
    gettimeofday( &t0, NULL );
}
static inline double measure_end( )
{
    gettimeofday( &t1, NULL );
    timersub( &t1, &t0, &tdiff );
    return tdiff.tv_sec + tdiff.tv_usec / 1e6;
}


void tests( std::vector<int> *vec )
{
    ///Normal for
    std::cout << "for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) (*vec)[i]++; - ";
    measure_begin( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) (*vec)[i]++;
    std::cout << measure_end( ) << "s" << std::endl;

    //Normal for, but with size
    std::cout << "for ( int i = 0; i < vec->size( ); i++ ) (*vec)[i]++; - ";
    measure_begin( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < vec->size( ); i++ ) (*vec)[i]++;
    std::cout << measure_end( ) << "s" << std::endl;

    //Ranged for
    std::cout << "for ( int &n : *vec ) n++; - ";
    measure_begin( );
    for ( int &n : *vec ) n++;
    std::cout << measure_end( ) << "s" << std::endl;
}


int main( )
{
    //Create a new vector using the new constructor
    std::cout << "default constructor..." << std::endl;
    std::vector <int> *vec = new std::vector <int>;

    //Data push
    std::cout << "pushing data..." << std::endl;
    measure_begin( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) vec->push_back( rand( ) ); 
    std::cout << "elapsed: " << measure_end( ) << "s" << std::endl;

    tests( vec );

    //Restart - this time set size in constructor
    delete vec;
    std::cout << "vector(N) constructor..." << std::endl;
    vec = new std::vector <int>;
    vec->reserve( N );
    std::cout << "vec.size() is now " << vec->size( ) << std::endl;

    //Data push
    std::cout << "pushing data..." << std::endl;
    measure_begin( );
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) vec->push_back( rand( ) ); 
    std::cout << "elapsed: " << measure_end( ) << "s" << std::endl;

    tests( vec );

    delete vec;

}
```

I'm compiling the code with GCC 7.30 with `-O3` flag enabled on Ubuntu 18.04.

As you can see, adding data to the vectors is slightly slower and modifying it can be up to two times slower with the `std::vector(N)` constructor. Looking at the results, it appears to me that all the range methods (`vector::begin`, `vector::end`) are taking more time in the second case.

I fail to explain myself possible reasons for this behavior. Does anyone know what's happening?

EDIT: It turns out that there's no performance issue after all. As Holt first pointed out in the comments section, in the second case the 2 latter `for` loops iterate over vector of twice the default size. When I use `vector::reserve` and default constructor, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Why do you allocate your vector dynamically (`*vec`)? Did you average the results? `int` of random values -> Unitialized or randomized?

Comment: Are the results stable across multiple runs? Are the results stable when you run the two cases in the opposite order? Are the results stable when you run the 3 individual cases in different orders? Was the first vector destroyed before the second was created?

Comment: @Holt The initial vector values come from `rand()` function. I allocate vector dynamically just to be able to use it twice for two tests. I will edit the question in a moment.

Comment: You should post code here.

Comment: @Jacajack There is a huge issue in your code. The first case loops over `N`, but the seconds over `2 * N`. If you do `vector<int>{N}` and then `N` push_back, you have a fector filled with `N` zeros, and then `N` random values, so it's quite logic that your tests take twice as long.

Comment: @Useless Yes, the results are stable across numerous runs. It also happens when order is reversed. The vector is indeed destroyed before second allocation.

Comment: If you construct with a size, the vector is already full, if you push back after that it will become even larger. If you just want to reserve memory, use the reserve() method.

Comment: This is the same issue as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51319486/9593596)

Comment: @Holt That's right... now I see. I'm an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulR With `reserve` it works perfectly - thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first vector gets N items added to it. The second vector is created as N items and then gets N items added to it, making it twice the size.

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, the second vector allocates space for N nits when it's created, no need to resize itself when it gets filled up, because it won't.

Also as a suggestion if you create the vector specifying it's size, you should replace it's elements using the subscript operator( operator[]), not push_back() since then you will have a vector of N elements with default int values and then you are trying to add one more to the end, resulting in a resize.

Note that a resize ill have to cpy all the previous elements, hence a vector which already has N elements performs worse.